# "Thu Jul 21 07:00:00 EDT 2016" change date format android to MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a

Tags: android, datetime

i try below code but its give Exception how to change date format like 6/21/2016 7:00 PM

```
    public static String parseDate(String time) {

    String outputPattern = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: please post your stacktrace...

Comment: please clarify: The given String `time`, is this `6/21/2016 7:00 PM` like you described in your question? Or is this what you want to get?

Comment: Unparseable date: "Thu Jul 21 07:00:00 EDT 2016" (at offset 0)

Comment: Input String :  "Thu Jul 21 07:00:00 EDT 2016"  and wants Output as " 6/21/2016 7:00 PM"

Comment: then follow Sanjeev´s answer, thats the correct one. You have created a wrong input format string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your input string by using following pattern

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

This will solve your UnParseableDate Exception.

Comment: Glad that helped you. Have fun coding :)

Comment: can we get only time without splitting string ? if give me sollution

Comment: yup, use `String outputPattern = "h:mm a";`

Comment: how to validate end time date is not greater than start time and date

Comment: Please ask a separate question for that.